# Session locked, Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: power-management

After leaving my laptop for a while, my Kubuntu session closed.  (I'm not sure which of the  various timeout criteria caused it.)  So I got a screen that said my session was locked and I needed to provide my password to unlock it.  That's a nuisance, not a big problem, but I'd like to fix it so timed-out sessions don't lock the session.

I assume there's something in System Settings to disable the lockout -- but where?  I looked in Power Management and found a setting "Lock screen on resume", but it's unchecked.
Is this possibly a bug?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an application called "Brightness and Lock" under it you'll find options that dictate how long your laptop can be left idle before turning off the screen and how long after the screen turns blank before a password is needed to unlock it with an option to require your password to wake from suspend.

Comment: I can't find any application like that.  The options that dictate how long the laptop can be left idle are under System Settings / Power Options.  There's an option there, which I would have thought to be the applicable one, for "lock screen on resume".  But I left that unchecked.

Comment: There's a reported bug for this problem, which is supposed to be solved "downstream", whatever that means.